# console log in nextJS is not working consistantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, console.log

I am new to nextJS.

using `npm run dev` ,
I hv changed the following in `package.json` for `console.log` to work:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev"
  }
}
```

- I hv written this component, works all fine.
- It's a selecttion to
  choose user language, which would then switch and store language
  settings to local storage.
- It works, but console log is not
  reflecting every change.
- What is more weird: it would only
  log to console when my language is set to "Japanese"(out of 3 languages to be chosen from).

If I use an `alert()` instead of `console.log`, it does return the correct value, but i think this is not good way to debug.

Here's my code:

```
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

const ChangeLang = (newLanguage: 'en' | 'zh' | 'ja', setLang: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<'en' | 'zh' | 'ja'>>) => {
    console.log('[-- Lang Change --] aiming at: ' + newLanguage');
    setLang(newLanguage); // Change and set language
    localStorage.setItem('langPref', newLanguage);
    const updatedLangPref = localStorage.getItem('langPref');
    console.log('User language preference is [Changed] to: ' + newLanguage);
    console.log('Local Storage is [Changed] to: ' + updatedLangPref);
};

const AutoSetLang = () => {
    const [lang, setLang] = useState<'en' | 'zh' | 'ja'>('zh'); // Default language

    const BrowserLang = () => {
        const userLanguages = navigator.languages || [navigator.language || navigator.language];
        const primaryLanguage = userLanguages[0]?.split('-')[0];
        console.log('[Browser] language is: ' + userLanguages);
        console.log('[Browser] language is read as: ' + primaryLanguage);
        return primaryLanguage as 'en' | 'zh' | 'ja';
    };

    const GetPref = () => {
        const storedPreference = localStorage.getItem('langPref'); // Get preference
        console.log('[Storage] preference was set to: ' + storedPreference);
        return storedPreference !== null;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('[--- UseEffect ---]');
        const detectLanguage = GetPref(); // Check if a language preference is stored
        console.log('Detect language:', detectLanguage);
        console.log('Stored preference:', BrowserLang());
        // Do only when nothing is set:
        if (!detectLanguage) {
            console.log('[--- No Set, so Now do ---]');
            const mylang: 'en' | 'zh' | 'ja' = BrowserLang();
            ChangeLang(mylang, setLang); // Set language based on detection
            console.log('Innit language preference is set to: ' + mylang);
        }else{
            const storedPreference = localStorage.getItem('langPref');
            ChangeLang(storedPreference as 'en' | 'zh' | 'ja', setLang);
            console.log('Loaded language preference is set to: ' + storedPreference);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <FormControl id="lang-select-form" sx={{mr: 1}}>
                {/* <InputLabel id="lang-select">{lang === 'zh' ? '中文' : lang === 'ja' ? '日本語' : 'en'}</InputLabel> */}
                <Select
                    labelId="lang-select"
                    id="lang-select"
                    value={lang}
                    label={lang === 'zh' ? '中文' : lang === 'ja' ? '日本語' : 'en'}
                    onChange={(event) => { ChangeLang(event.target.value as 'en' | 'zh' | 'ja', setLang); }}
                >
                    <MenuItem id ="select_zh" value={'zh'}>中文</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem id ="select_en"  value={'en'}>ENG</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem id ="select_ja"  value={'ja'}>日本語</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </>
    );
};

export default AutoSetLang;
export { ChangeLang };
```

There are a lot of `console.log` happening, and they are refelcts in console only when "ja" is set. While everything else is still working as expected.

We can focus only on the first `ChangeLang()`, none of the console log is showing in the console, unless i am changing to "ja" with it.